# Is List<T> a linked list?

Tags: c#, .net

Is `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` a type of [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)*(not the `LinkedList<T>` class)*?

> A **linked list** is a data structure consisting of a group of nodes which together represent a sequence. Under the simplest form, each node is composed of a datum and a reference *(in other words, a link)* to the next node in the sequence.
>
> [image: Linear Linked List]
> <sup>A linked list whose nodes contain two fields: an integer value and a link to the next node. 
> The last node is linked to a terminator used to signify the end of the list.</sup>
>
> *wikipedia.org*

If it is, what kind of linked list is it?

Comment: @Adrian Iftode: This question isn't asking when to choose `List<T>` over `LinkedList<T>`.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, yes, I should have post this as a comment

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) is backed by an array - it's essentially a generic version of `ArrayList` from .NET 1.0. From the docs:

> The `List<T>` class is the generic equivalent of the `ArrayList` class. It implements the `IList<T>` generic interface using an array whose size is dynamically increased as required.

Note that due to being backed by an array, its access via indexers is O(1) as opposed to the O(N) for a linked list.

If you want a linked list, use [`LinkedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx). Note that this is a *doubly*-linked list. I don't believe .NET exposes a *singly*-linked list type.

Comment: You mean it is managed in the memory like an array? But how can I add an indefinite number of objects in it? And I can remove an item from it?

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona: I mean that it has an array variable internally. The array is a fixed size (as *all* arrays are in .NET) but when the list needs to grow, a new array is created and the existing elements are copied. Likewise when you remove an item, it just copies the rest of the elements to their new correct place.

Answer (score 7):

`List<T>`, from a... technical perspective, is **NOT** a type of linked list.

If you want to have a linked list in C# :

- either use the built-in `LinkedList<T>` type (for double-linked
  lists)
- or create an implementation of your own (if you want a
  singly-linked one) - [here's an example](http://web.archive.org/web/20111107161759/http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=169)

Comment: The link for the example is dead.

Comment: @Edward I have updated the link